# UI-Grid Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, http, frontend, angular-ui-grid, grafana

Hi guys I'm trying to setup expandable grid  http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/216_expandable_grid

But getting the error oh http request :

TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at new eval (ui-grid.js?bust=1466737921408:3164)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js?bust=1466737921408:4625)
    at $controllerInit (angular.js?bust=1466737921408:10027)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js?bust=1466737921408:8965)
    at eval (angular.js?bust=1466737921408:9362)
    at processQueue (angular.js?bust=1466737921408:15757)
    at eval (angular.js?bust=1466737921408:15773)
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js?bust=1466737921408:17025)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js?bust=1466737921408:16841)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js?bust=1466737921408:17133)

this is my code:

```js
gridOptions: {
  paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75],
  paginationPageSize: 25,
  expandableRowTemplate: '<div ui-grid="row.entity.subGridOptions" style="width: 150px;"></div>',
  onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
    console.log('getting here');
    gridApi.expandable.on.rowExpandedStateChanged($scope, $http, function(row) {
      console.log(row);
      if (row.isExpanded) {
        row.entity.subGridOptions = {
          columnDefs: [{
            name: 'name'
          }, {
            name: 'gender'
          }, {
            name: 'company'
          }]
        };

        $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100.json')
          .success(function(data) {
            row.entity.subGridOptions.data = data[1];
          })
          .error(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: shouldnt this line  `row.entity.subGridOptions.data = data[1];` be `row.entity.subGridOptions.data = data;`

Comment: That was first that I tried

Comment: I think it's probably some other property of that data object that was returned. Do a console.log(data) in the success() call and see what's in it.

Comment: Are you sure that the 'data' mentioned in the console error is from the http call? +1 for trying the console.log as recommended by @S.Baggy. If everything checks out fine with the http return, then it's likely that `subGridOptions` is undefined.